# How to open intent within an android layout - To specific area, not in a fullscreen

Tags: android, layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm trying to to open activity within my activity. User clicks button on the left side of the layout and the intent is shown on the right side. How this could be done while keeping the leftside buttons visible? Everytime I tried to start intent, it is opened on top of my layout covering it.

So the logic is same as tarketing HTML link to certain frame, but on android with activities/intents.

Mockup:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHqKd.jpg

**Update:**

I'd like to make this question more specific. If I open intent from my fragment it opens on fullscreen instead of filling only the are of current fragment:

```
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String url = "http://www.google.com";
            Intent google = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            google.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            getActivity().startActivity(google);
        }
    });
```

How to open intent from a fragment, so it fills only fragment, not the whole screen?

Comment: Yes I fiqured yesterday that fragments could have some sort of answer. However could fragments only work with your own classes within a project? I tried to lauch intent from a fragment and it opened fullscreen, which is not a effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is fragments. Fragments can easily be added and detached from activity as you wish. So what you basically need to do is add a fragment on a button click, when the other button is clicked you should remove this fragment and add another.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I tested launching intent from a fragment, but the activity started fullscreen, instead of a fullfilling layout only partly.

Answer (score 0):

Try dis code use a WebView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/frst_btn"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="FIRST"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/second_btn"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="SECOND"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Use this code also

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById (R.id.run);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = "URL";

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());  
        webView.loadUrl(url);          
            }
        });



    private class Callback extends WebViewClient{  

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return (false);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nice layout. But lets say I want to open default gallery from the first button: Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
gallery.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY); How do I target it to open in webview?

Comment: dear u want to open a browser or some thing else

Comment: Browser is just a one of the dozens intents I want to open in one particular area on my layout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I believe webview can load only URLs and other web-content, while I'm trying to navigate with native android apps like gallery, webbrowser and my own classes.